# Why was leek considered holy in the Edda?

Tags: vikings, norse-mythology

> 4 .
> Then  Bur’s  sons  lifted the  level  land,
> Mithgarth  the  mighty  there  they  made;
> The  sun  from  the  south warmed  the  stones of earth,
> And  green  was  the  ground with  growing  leeks.

[Poetic Edda, Strophe 4, Verse 4](https://archive.org/details/poeticedda00edda/page/4/mode/2up)

If you look at this commented book from 1923, the  author explained it as

> Leeks:  the  leek  was  often  used  as  the  symbol  of  fine growth

The [German version](https://archive.org/details/dieaeltereeddas00wenzgoog/page/2/mode/2up) of the poetic Edda I am reading through, a commented version from 1877, explains that, translated;

> 3. Leek (Allium) is regarded in the Edda as holy herb.

I could not however find anything as to why, and especially since leeks aren't spectacular or extraordinary in any ways I couldn't really leave this small detail alone and wanted to know the source of leeks being 'holy'. I understand why Oak trees, for example, have such an importance in the Edda -  they are an amazing building material, they are around everywhere and these cultures are literally built on Oak trees. I would understand medicinal plants, things like elderberries but why leek?

Addendum:

When researching this further, and I am not sure if this is a dead end - Another word for leek is allium. Allium is a lot of things, including wild garlic, onions, chives and many more. Of those, especially wild garlic is a plant that is very famous as a wild and healing plant. I could imagine this. Another thing of research showed btw that leeks were used to [revive a horses penis and a gods head](https://earthandstarryheaven.com/2016/04/27/mimir-volsi/#more-3642)

Comment: To me "often used as the symbol of fine growth" seems self-explanatory. It's grows vigorously, is useful, arguably has phallic characteristics, so the symbolism is unsurprising. What sort of evidence would definitively answer the question?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why not?

First off, this is the original:

```
Áðr Burs synir
bjöðum um ypðu,
þeir er Miðgarð
mœran skópu;
sól skein sunnan
á salar steina,
þá var grund gróin
grœnum lauki.
```

"Leek" is one of the reconstructed meanings of the [laguz / laukaz rune](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laguz), a symbol of fertility, so there is a chance that "lauki" stands here as a "backronym" symbol for general fertility.

It is a [hardy plant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leek#Form) that grows well even far to the north, and can be left in the ground for later harvesting during early winter, making it an excellent food source. That alone would probably be sufficient to explain it being mentioned in that way.

The leek is the [national emblem of Wales](https://www.historic-uk.com/HistoryUK/HistoryofWales/The-Leek-National-emblem-of-the-Welsh/), where it was considered...

> ...a medicine to cure a variety of illnesses [...] a cure for the common cold, alleviating the pains of childbirth...

...which is still true today, a good hot soup would still be considered "a good thing to do" when you don't feel that well.

Wikipedia (with attribution to *Glantz, Animal and plant life in the Torah*) states:

> The Hebrew Bible talks of חציר, identified by commentators as leek, and says it is abundant in Egypt.

Which is corroborated by archaeological evidence. So it was not just the Norse that valued it.

As for general Norse mysticism, note that it is very different from monotheistic mysticism. Things are not always huge and majestic (like oaks), because the gods are not associated with omnipotence. "Holy" therefore means a lot less. Odin did not create the world and all there was on it, but is the son of the son of the giant that was licked from primeval ice by a cow. Thor's chariot was drawn by goats, Freija's chariot by cats...